# .getRowIndex(); and .getColumnIndex(); Are No Shown as Options in the GridPane Class in JavaFX in Netbeans. How Can I Fix This?

Tags: java, javafx, netbeans, gridpane

I am using JavaFX in Netbeans. I am also using Scene Builder to create the FXML file. I have a GridPane named grid1 with two columns and two rows. I want to find out if their are any child objects in the grid. I would imagine that I use `grid1.getRowIndex();` and `grid1.getColumnIndex();`. I have seen those used in previous examples. The problem is that netbeans does not give those options. It only allows me to put grid1. The process works in Eclipse, though, but I want it to work in NetBeans. Pictures are included.

Thanks!

[image]

[image]

Comment: The links are the images.  I import javafx.scene.layout.GridPane; each time.

Comment: Thanks! I think I figured out the problem!

Answer (score 1):

I figured out the answer to my problem, although I think it is a little strange.  While I tried grid1.getRowIndex(); and it did not work, GridPane.getRowIndex(token1); did work.  token1 is a name of the child. I don't know why it would work with the object type and not the individual object name.

Comment: [`GridPane.getRowIndex`](https://openjfx.io/javadoc/11/javafx.graphics/javafx/scene/layout/GridPane.html#getRowIndex(javafx.scene.Node)) is a _static_ method. While you are allowed to invoke static methods on instances, the IDE is likely smart enough to know when you are trying to invoke a method on an instance vs on a class. So when you typed `grid1.getr` it filtered out the static methods. If you were to type more, say, `grid1.getRowI` it might have shown you the static method since there is no longer any matching instance methods. At least, that's how Intellij IDEA behaves.

Comment: Thanks for your help!